# javascript regular expretion issue with facebook links

Tags: javascript, regex, facebook

i am trying to to the following

```
new RegExp(/(^(https:\/\/)((w{3}\.)?)facebook\.com\/(?:[^\s()\\\[\]{};:'",<>?«»“”‘’]){5,255}$)|(^$)/i).test('https://www.facebook.com/NocApps?ref=ts&fref=ts')
```

but this returns false

if i remove the "?" from "https://www.facebook.com/NocAppsref=ts&fref=ts" it returns true. why?
what am i missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are excluding `?` from possible characters here `[^\s()\\\[\]{};:'",<>?«»“”‘’]`